# TensorBoard log dir problem in Windows and semicolon

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I dont know if it is a problem with TensorBoard itself or I am doing something wrong here...
When I provide a path with log_dir, it looks like a semicolon is added at the end, and it is using forward slash when I am on Windows.

Here is my code:

```py
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
callbacks = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='log\\' + timestamp,
                                            histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False)
```

I tried to use Path from pathlib, but it does not work either.

```py
timestamp = Path(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d--%H:%M:%S'))
log_dir = 'Graph' / timestamp
```

The error looks like:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a directory: log/2019-04-25-00:15:25; Invalid argument
```

Any ideas...?

Edit:

Yes, if I print my timestamp it has no semicolon at the end.

**Versions**:
Python: 3.6.7
Keras: 2.2.4
Tensorflow: 1.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows OS, `/ \ : * ? " < > |` this are the characters which are not allowed to create file name. Because of the colon (`:`) you are not able to create a folder.